# "other" option in dropdown menu and setting values

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a combobox  with an option  "other". user can select an entry from the list or select option "other". if they select "other"  a text box will disply below to enter a new account number. see the code below:

```
              <td>1. Account Number<span class="bodyCopy"><font color="#ff0000"> * </font></span>: 
        <html:select name="reDataForm" property="Member.accountNumber"  styleClass="formContent" 
          style="width:80px" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
         <html:options collection="<%= WorkConstants.NewDropdowns.PACCT %>" property="value" labelProperty="label" styleClass="formContent"/>
        
         </html:select>

    
         <div id="div1"></div>
```

It works fine. But when the page refreshes, the text box disappears as no code to keep it there.
1)how do I keep the text box if the use was selected "Other" and entered a new account number in the text box ?  OR if we can add the text box value into the dropdown list, that will also work.
2) Also how to set the text box value into the same variable Member.accountNumber ?

please help me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a little bit of javascript on an onLoad event to check if other is selected, and display the text box
2. You can't submit the value as the same name as the select box. instead, submit as a second name and process accordingly in your ActionForm on the serverside.

Comment: i tried like this below : <% String selectedValue=request.getParameter("Member.accountNumber"); %> <c:set var="selection" value="<%=selectedValue%>" /> <c:choose> <c:when test="${selection == 'Other' }"> <% out.println("in other");%><br> <html:text name="reDataForm" property="Member.accountNumber" styleClass="formContent" maxlength="9" size="9"/>' </c:when> </c:choose>                                                          it checks if the user is selected "Other" -works fine. but when it displays the text box, it displays the page with a warning. why ?

Comment: I was thinking to do it JavaScript rather than jsp tags. Always have the text box on the page, just hidden, and when the page loads, use JavaScript to check the value of the select box and set whether the text box should be hidden or not.